# Linux: File both exists and not exists

Tags: php, linux, bash

I am writing a PHP application, and I've just encountered a really wierd error. After a recent move to a new (Ubuntu) server, i started getting fatal errors on a require_once statement. So obviously the file doesn't exist, or the file permissions are wrong, right?

No, as it turns out:

**The file does exist**
The file is checked out from an SVN repository. When I go into the folder and list the files (*ls* or *ls -l*) the file is clearly there and has the correct file size. When I update the file in the repository and update the working copy, the changes are copied to the working copy. The file has permissions 755, so everyone should be able so see and read it. Other files in the same directory are working just fine.

**The file also doesn't exist:**
PHP exits with a fatal error because the file can't be found. If I use the *find*-command, the file is not found. If I try to use *nano* to edit the file, it claims it does not exist. If I start typing the filename and press tab to autocomplete, it can't find the file.

This behaviour has now happened on two separate servers, but it works fine on a third server. All the servers run Ubuntu 10.04.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

EDIT:
File name is AdminIpv4RangeAddFormHandler.inc.

Full error message, with file paths obscured:

```
Warning: require_once(fullpath/AdminIpv4RangeAddFormHandler.inc): failed to open
stream: No such file or directory in fullpath/anotherfile.inc on line 34 Fatal error: 
require_once(): Failed opening required 'fullpath/AdminIpv4RangeAddFormHandler.inc' 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in fullpath/anotherfile.inc on line 
34
```

The following command produces no output:

```
find -name AdminIpv4RangeAddFormHandler.inc -ls
```

A regular *ls -li* outputs (amongst others) this row:

```
2233407 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1597 2011-12-13 08:02 AdminIPv4RangeAddFormHandler.inc
```

Comment: Can you add some `ls -li` and `find ... -ls` output here? This sure sounds awkward.

Comment: Asking questions about PHP errors **without posting the actual error message** makes absolutely no sense. Please, don't waste too much words describing the problem. This is not an enthusiast novelists site, this is enthusiast programmers site. Copy/paste of actual error messages and console output is enough

Comment: include the svn co & export process, how you use the find, how you use the ls

Comment: SVN Checkout is done in the standard way: sudo svn checkout svn://[REPOSITORY_URL] .

Comment: Your filename has "IP" capitalized, while your require_once() has it as "Ip"...

Comment: are you running your scripts under root?

Comment: Consider establishing a naming convention to use Ip or IP consequently.

Comment: The capitalization turned out to be the problem. The convention used otherwise in the application is "Ip", not "IP". Thank you all for taking time to help me on this.

Comment: No worries.  Hope you didn't downvote me without even trying it first :P

Comment: @landons are you hitting the jackpot?

Comment: Haha.  Jackpot of getting screwed? Yup.

Comment: @landons, The downvote was not from me. I upvoted you, but sarnold's answer was most accurate, so he got the accept. Again, thank you all for helping me on this.

Comment: @MW. will you still insist on camelCase?

Comment: @ajreal: Yes, I originally learned programming in Java, so it's sort of in my backbone.

Comment: I nailed it first try, giving good SCM and OS advice.  You're a dick ;)

Comment: @landons: Well, if I am, then I guess I got the downvotes that I deserve ;P

Comment: I'll give you one back.  I was enjoying the humor of it all :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a good long look at your filenames:

```
AdminIpv4RangeAddFormHandler  # from PHP
AdminIpv4RangeAddFormHandler  # from find command
AdminIPv4RangeAddFormHandler  # from ls output
      ^
```

You should pick `IP` or `Ip` and stick with the decision *everywhere*.

Comment: Haha.  I get an accept and downvote, and you get an upvote.  I'm upvoting you again just out of reverse spite.

Comment: "Reverse spite", hehehe, that's awesome. :D Don't worry too much about the points though, you're up 70-2, I'm up 30+15, you're still _way_ ahead in our imaginary race. :)

Comment: Haha.  Pretending to be worried about it paid off.  But still, I've never had someone downvote my answer, then upvote it, then accept it, then unnaccept it.  My head is spinning.

Comment: You've still got the one lone downvote, whoever left it didn't retract it later. Go figure.

Comment: Eh, maybe I'll earn a badge out of it.

Answer (score 9):

**Be careful switching OS's, as some are case sensitive, and others aren't.**

I use my Mac for development (case insensitive), so it doesn't matter what casing I use for file_exists() or include_once() etc.  Then I deployed to Ubuntu 11 (case sensitive), and all my includes stopped working.  I suspect you have the same exact problem.

The tricky part for me was, while using git, my version control didn't detect changes in file name case as a modification.  I actually had to rename every file with some sort of prefix, commit and deploy, rename them back to what they should be (with consistent capitalization!), and finally commit and deploy again.  It was a complete pain.

Moral of the story--code for your production system, not your dev system.

Comment: I realize that.  If you don't even know if your OS is case sensitive, I suspect you should consider that with your SCM too...